# Как отобразить картинку в img html

Tags: html, изображения, img

у меня появилась проблема в том, что не отображается картинка в теге img.

Вот структура проекта:

```
project
    apps
      data
         image.jpg
templates
    index.html
```

в index я указываю такой img:

```
<img src="/project/apps/data/image.jpg">
```

Но картинка не отображается, как это можно исправить?

UPD:

```
{% extends 'base_html.html' %}

{% block style %}href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/post_style.css') }}"{% endblock %}
{% block phone_style %}href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/post_style.css') }}"{% endblock %}
{% block title %}post{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="post-card">
    <div class="post-image">
        <img src="/posts/data/images/post0.jpg" alt="что-то пошло не так">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: 1. убедитесь что путь к картинке правильный 2. не парные теги(не имеющие отдельного закрывающего тега) такие как img, br тоже надо закрывать. `<img src='#' alt='не правильный'>` `<img src='#' alt='правильный' />`

Answer (score 0):

у вас index.html находится в другой папке, сначала выйдите с нее а потом уже обращайтесь к картинке

```
<img src="../project/apps/data/image.jpg">
```